# React - Composition VS Configuration

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I am currently working on a project that requires dynamically injecting one component into another.

My project is using Redux, so I came up with two possible solutions which both have their advantages and disadvantages, but I don't know which one to choose. I know that by nature, React encourages composition, but I'm still curious to know if the second approach (simpler and faster to use) is still good :

```
export const SlideOverComponents = {
  'UserCreate': UserCreate,
  'UserUpdate': UserUpdate,
};
```

The idea is to register all components that can be injected as a key value pair, and dispatch a Redux action with the key and the props required by this component.

```
{(!!componentKey && !!SlideOverComponents[componentKey]) && React.createElement(SlideOverComponents[componentKey], props)}
```

Then in my parent container, I just read this key and use the React.createElement to display the injected one.

This solution is working fine and is easy and fast to use because I just have to register any new component to the object to make it work.

Is this approach "ok" ? Or should I use composition ?

(I'm asking from a "good practice" or "anti-pattern" point of view.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's fine, as long as the interface between all of the `SlideOverComponents` are completely identical. Your code is more verbose than it needs to be. You don't need `createElement` either if you assign it to a variable first

```js
const Component = SlideOverComponents[componentKey]
return (
  <div>
    {Component && <Component {...props} />}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: What do you mean by " as long as the interface... are completely identical" ? The props aren't identical, but that's not a problem if this is what you meant

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Depending on how different they are, it can be notoriously difficult to write a type definition for `SlideOverComponents`. Usually when you are grouping together things that accept completely different props, you should question whether or not that's the right design decision to begin with

Comment: `type SlideOverComponentsKeyType = keyof typeof SlideOverComponents;

const injectInSlideOver = <T extends SlideOverComponentsKeyType = SlideOverComponentsKeyType>(
    key: T,
    options: SlideOverState['options'],
    ...props: (React.ComponentProps<typeof SlideOverComponents[T]> extends object ? [React.ComponentProps<typeof SlideOverComponents[T]>] : [])
  )`

I've actually made an hook that export this method. It's take 2 or 3 arguments depending of wether or not, the component require props. The only "problem" was wether it is a good idea or not to use this pattern over compositi

Answer (score 0):

### Edit:

I noticed that you are using TypeScript from other answers. Considering that, I still think you can use Composition but with types using [String Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) like this:

```
type SlideOverComponentsType = "update" | "create";

type SlideOverComponentsProps = UserUpdateProps | UserCreateProps;

type SlideOverProps = {
  key: SlideOverComponentsType;
} & SlideOverComponentsProps;

function SlideOver({ key, ...props }: SlideOverProps) {
  switch (key) {
    case "update":
      return <UserUpdate {...props} />;
    case "create":
      return <UserCreate {...props} />;
    default:
      return null; // this will never happen but need to be addressed
  }
}
```

And with an approach like that, you don't need an "Object" to store all the possible types of `SlideOverComponents`. You also guarantee that the props will always be using the proper interface and if eventually, you pass it wrongly TS will warn you about that.

Again: consider using types instead of declaring "options" as objects for cases like this.

Hope that this could help you or give you some good ideas!

### Original Answer:

You can still use Composition for this and create some kind of check or `switch` statement inside the "Generic" Component. That way you could avoid adding so many checks(`if`s) outside of the parent component and guarantee that eventually non-existing `keys` could fallback to a default behavior or even to an error.

There are several ways of implementing it but one using `switch` that I like is this one:

```js
function UserInteraction({ key, ...props }) {
  switch (key) {
    case "create": {
      return <UserCreate {...props} />;
    }
    case "update": {
      return <UserUpdate {...props} />;
    }
    default: {
      return null;
      // or you could thrown an error with something like
      throw new Error(`Error: key ${key} not present inside component User`);
    }
  }
}
```

You could also use the `Object.keys()` method to accomplish almost the same behavior:

```js
const UserInteractionOptions = {
  "create": UserCreate,
  "update": UserUpdate,
}

function UserInteraction({ key, ...props }) {
  if (!Object.keys(UserInteractionOptions).includes(key)) {
    return null;
    // or you could thrown an error with something like
    throw new Error(`Error: key ${key} not present inside component User`);
  } 

  const InteractionComponent = UserInteractionOptions[key];
  
  return <InteractionComponent {...props} />;
}
```

The main idea is to isolate the logic from deciding which component to render (and if it can be rendered) inside that component.

For future reading, you could check on **TypeScript** and how this can be easily handled by types, coercion, and the checks for non-present `keys` could be made before even the code runs locally.

---

A little of nitpicking: you are not "injecting" a Component inside another Component. You are just passing a `key` to deciding if the Parent Component renders or not the Child component through a flag. The injection of one Component into another involves passing the full component as a prop and just rendering it (or customizing it, eventually).
You could look at how React decides to render the `children` prop and how it decides if it is `null`, a `string`, or a `ReactComponent` to render an actual component. Also, a good topic to research is Dependency Injection.

As a simple example, injecting a component could looks like this:

```js
function Label({ text }) {
  return <p>{text}</p>;
}

function Input({ Label, ...props }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Label />
      <input {...props} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I dont really see, in this case, why it is a better solution to use composition rather than configuration pattern. This seems more verbose and complex, but for what gain ? For the TS part, as you can see in my answer above, my function used to "inject" a component is strongly typed. It requires a third argument if your component has props, or not if it ain't. ( and of course it is type with the component props type ).

Comment: About being more verbose, I totally agree. About being more complex, I feel that a more descriptive approach could give more information about use cases and create good practices in your codebase.

As you described, there's nothing wrong with your proposed solution and adding it to a hook. It is actually ok. You can choose what makes more sense to you. Just remember: React is a **Component-based UI Framework**. If you start to create ways of not using it as it was conceived, you'll not take full advantage of the framework.